# How to implement reCAPTCHA with AJAX for sending mail in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to add Google's recaptcha in my website's contact form. I've used the `<input type="submit">` instead of button tag for submitting the form. But it doesn't work with AJAX. And with button tag, the captcha response is always empty. You can check the problem on [vipiny.com](http://vipiny.com).

This is the contact form.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
    <div>
        <label for="contactName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactName" name="contactName">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="contactSubject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactSubject" name="contactSubject">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea cols="50" rows="3" id="contactMessage" name="contactMessage"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha captcha" data-theme="light" data-sitekey="6LfAkhQUAAAAAC2D3LxhB9XtYeoJGhuvR31sq9HW"></div>
    <div>
        <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form> <!-- Form End -->
```

And I'm using ajax to send the data to sendMail.php file.

```
$('form#contactForm button.submit').click(function() {

  $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

  var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
  var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
  var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
  var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

  var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
           '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

  $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(msg) {

        // Message was sent
        if (msg == 'OK') {
           $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
           $('#message-warning').hide();
           $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
           $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
        }
        // There was an error
        else {
           $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
           $('#message-warning').html(msg);
            $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
        }

      }

  });
  return false;   }); });
```

And this is so far my sendMail.php file. I'm trying to validate that if `$error['captcha']` is empty along with other input field checks, the mail will be sent.

```
$secret = "<--secret key-->";
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    // echo "GOT response:".$response."<br/>";
}
else{
    // echo "No reCAPTCHA response.<br/>";
}

//Verify response data
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$user_ip");
$responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
if(!$responseData->success){
    $error['captcha'] = "Please prove that you're not a robot.";    
}
```

Any suggestions what might be going wrong?

Comment: can you do a inspect element on your html and post that? seems there is more code to recaptcha than we are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `?` after the url

```
url: "inc/sendEmail.php?",
```

OR

you could leave out the `?` and send your data like

```
data: { this: this, that: that, another: another},
```

also since you are not posting the `g-recaptcha-response` to the php file with the form, but instead with AJAX you have to send the post manually to your php file.

```
var g-recaptcha-response= $('#contactForm .g-recaptcha-response').val();

var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
       '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage + '&g-recaptcha-response=' + g-recaptcha-response;
```

you made also need this to confirm the recaptcha in php

```
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
```

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php

Comment: Thank you @CesarBielich, AJAX was not sending the response and little correction on your code there was one <space> while creating data string in '&g-recaptcha-response='